# (eval):13: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Not sure why I'm getting this error. Here's the code:

```
puts "Please input an integer"
puts ">>> A positive input stores how many numbers are >, < or = to 1000"
puts ">>> -1 terminates the application and outputs how many numbers were >, < or = to 1000"

num = gets.chomp

i = num.to_i

while num != "-1"

    if i > 1000
        greater += 1
    elsif i < 1000
        less += 1
    elsif i == 1000
        equal += 1
    elsif i < 0
        puts "Please only enter positive integers"
    end
end

puts "Number of integers greater than 1000 = #{greater}"
puts "Number of intergers less than 1000 = #{less}"
puts "Number of integers equal to 1000 = #{equal}"

gets
```

The code is obviously trying to compare inputted numbers to see if they are greater than, less than or equal to 1000, then store them in variables which are than displayed once -1 is input.

Comment: `greater` `less` and `equal` are not defined.. `greater = less = equal = 0`

Comment: I...am such an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: Initially I missed the error message being in the title.  Some of us tend to skim titles and overlook valuable information they may contain.  That may be our problem, not yours, but better, I think, to include all essential information in the body of the question.  When showing error messages, you should also indicate the line on which the exception was raised.  Those new to Ruby sometimes pay less attention to the content of error messages than they should.  A careful reading will often pinpoint your mistake.

Comment: Indeed! It was the word method that threw me off. I'll make sure not to just put the error message in the title next time!

Comment: @Alex in Ruby `+` is a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing your `greater`, `less` and `equal` variables. Try adding

```
greater = 0
less = 0
equal = 0
```

or, if you prefer the shorter version that uses multiple assignments

```
greater = less = equal = 0
```

before the while cycle

Comment: Chubas vente a wizeline